# Placing variables in a combobox from a c# file

Tags: c#, combobox

I am having a strange event happen when my program executes. I have it set to where values from a database that is compiled in my .cs file called Data are suppose to populate the combobox. Here is the last post I made where I posted my code for the [Data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570597/c-sharp-public-class-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)
. I have used a variable to instantiate with but it gives me the name of the program. What can I do differently or just do in general to fix this? The person I am basing my program off only called the variables from the file and put them in there respective fields.

```
public Data Data { get; set; }
public Label Label { get; set; }

public Form1()
{
    Label Label = new Label()
    InitializeComponent();

    CmboBoxLabel.Items.Add(new Label(Label.Name,Label.Code));
}
```

Comment: It really isn't clear what you're asking. What do you mean when you say `I have used a variable to instantiate with but it gives me the name of the program.`?

Comment: Also, what is `Label`? Is that a `System.Windows.Forms.Label` or your own class?

Comment: @neoistheone Label is a class and when i run the program the combobox displays the name of my form i am working in. Not a database object the form it's named after

Comment: `Label` is a class that you wrote? And further, how does this `Label Label = new Label()` even work when you've already got a member declared above `public Label Label { get; set; }`. There has got to be some code missing here.

Comment: No offense meant but I think you should find a book or a good site that will teach you the basics first